# Strange SIGABRT error using UIViewController

Tags: ios, xcode, sigabrt

I'm getting a very odd SIGABRT error when adding subviews to a `UIScrollView`.

Basically, I am looping through and loading a series of subviews from nibs whose names are stored in an array (pages):

```
 int rollingXPos = self.view.frame.size.width/2;

    for (int i = 0; i < pages.count; i++) {
        UIViewController *newPage = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:[pages objectAtIndex:i] bundle:nil];
        newPage.view.center = CGPointMake(rollingXPos, self.view.center.y);
        [scrollView addSubview:newPage.view];
        rollingXPos += scrollView.frame.size.width;
    }
```

This apparently works fine as long as the XIB files do not have any connections to their owner class files (subclasses of UIViewController). As soon as I add any IBOutlets the SIBABRT error is triggered at

```
newPage.view.center = CGPointMake(rollingXPos, self.view.center.y);
```

If I change the code to ignore the file's owner and instead subclass `UView` and set the class for the top level view of the xib to be that, then it all works fine.

I have no idea what's causing this, any help appreciated!

Many thanks.